# Empty Select List - Disabled by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using asp.net MVC, and I am trying to create an empty SelectList that is disabled by default.

The idea is to have a cascading dropdown list, and when I call my `Create` controller on `GET`, my second dropdown list is not available. However, if I am calling `Create` on `POST`, I want a jQuery function to populate that dropdown.

In my controller, I have the following line to initialize the Dropdown:

`ViewBag.SOME_VARIABLE = Enumerable.Empty();`

I was trying to avoid disabling it in my view, doing something like:

```
Html.DropDownList("SOME_VARIABLE", null, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

because I do not want it to be disabled on `POST` calls.

In the end, I want my HTML to be rendered like:

```
<select ... disabled></select>
```

If my requirements are not possible, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this without explicitly setting the `disabled` attribute (form controls are not disabled by default). By why? - if your initially using `Enumerable.Empty()` then there is nothing to select anyway - its the equivalent of being disabled.

Comment: I just wanted to provide the user a "disabled feel", i.e, a grayed out box that is not clickable. Thank you for your input anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `ViewBag.disabled = false` in the `POST` Action
and in your view just print the viewbag value in hidden field and read it using jquery after page load and then you can enable the drop down or leave it disabled

Comment: I was hoping for a cleaner option, i.e, setting my `SelectList` to disabled without a flag variable, but I will use this as a last resort.